# PHP/SQL Issues on Posting Data to Database w/ cURL

Tags: php, mysql, json, curl

Below you will find the code.

I am trying to get this to retrieve JSON data, and post the values to my database.

JSON Structure and in which order is being output...

```
[{
    "record_locator": "value",
    "status": "value",
    "area": "value",
    "region": "value",
    "name": "value",
    "position":"value",
    "phone_": "value",
    "project_manager": "value",
    "ipad_email": "value",
    "email": "value",
    "team_leader": "value",
    "regional": "value",
    "title": "value",
    "start_date": "value",
    "employee_id_number": "value",
}]
```

For easy eyes...

**$VAR = MY TABLE KEY = JSON KEY**

```
$area   =area   =area
    $email  =email  =email
    $ipad_email =ipad_email =ipad_email
    $empid  =empid  =employee_id_number
    $fullname   =fullname   =name
    $manager    =manager    =If Clause
    $mobilenumber   =mobilenumber   =phone_
    $record_locator =record =record_locator
    $status =status =status
    $region =region =region
    $position   =position   =position
    $project_manager    =project_manager    =project_manager
    $team_leader    =team_leader    =team_leader
    $regional   =regional   =regional
    $title  =title  =title
    $startdate  =startdate  =startdate
```

I've done a simple echo test of the value and they're grabbing it, just for some reason its not posting to the database. I cant figure it out sadly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. **THIS IS NOT WORKING.**

```
<html>
                <head>
                <style>
                td {
                    text-align:center;
                    border: 1px solid black;
                }
                </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                <div style="margin-top:5%; width:300px; margin:auto; border: 1px solid black; padding:3px;"><center><p id="container">Loading...</p></div>
                <?php

                $error_msg = "";
                        $url="someurl.com";

                         $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

        $json = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $rdata = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    $c=0;
    $repverified = 0;

    foreach ($rdata as $data) { 

    //  Assigned key            JSON KEY 
    $user_rl    = $rdata[$c]['record_locator'];
    $status = $rdata[$c]['status'];
    $area   = $rdata[$c]['area'];
    $region = $rdata[$c]['region'];
    $fullname   = $rdata[$c]['name'];
    $position   = $rdata[$c]['position'];
    $mobilenumber   = $rdata[$c]['phone_'];
    $project_manager    = $rdata[$c]['project_manager'];
    $ipad_email     = $rdata[$c]['ipad_email'];
    $email  = $rdata[$c]['email'];
    $team_leader    = $rdata[$c]['team_leader'];
    $regional   = $rdata[$c]['regional'];
    $title  = $rdata[$c]['title'];
    $startdate  = $rdata[$c]['start_date'];
    $empid  = $rdata[$c]['employee_id_number'];


        if(
            $fullname       == $rdata[$c]['project_manager'] || 
            $fullname       == $rdata[$c]['team_leader'] || 
            $fullname       == $rdata[$c]['regional'] || 
            $fullname       == $rdata[$c]['director']) 
                {
                $manager = 'YES';
                } 
        else {
                $manager = 'NO';
             }

            // Insert the new user into the database 
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO memberss (
    record,
    status,
    area,
    region,
    fullname,
    manager,
    position,
    mobilenumber,
    project_manager,
    ipad_email,
    email,
    team_leader,
    regional,
    title,
    startdate,
    empid

    )
    VALUES (
    ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

   $insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

    // Insert the new user into the database
    if ($insert_stmt)
    {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssss',$user_rl,$status,$area,
                $region,$fullname,$manager,$position,$mobilenumber,
                $project_manager,$ipad_email,$email,$team_leader,
                $regional,$title,$startdate,$empid);

        // Execute the prepared query.
        if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
            header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
        }
    }
    }

    echo    '<div>Check to ensure we are grabbing the values</div>';
    echo    '<td>'. $user_rl    .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $status .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $area   .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $region .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $fullname   .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $manager    .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $position   .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $mobilenumber   .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $project_manager    .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $ipad_email .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $email  .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $team_leader    .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $regional   .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $title  .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $startdate  .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $empid  .'</td><br>';


        $c++;


        echo "<script>document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'Registration Completed!<br><b> Active Users will now be visible</b>';</script>";
        ?>
```

I have even tried to change my if statement and bind_params and still no luck

```
if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            }
        }
        } else {
        // Insert the new user into the database 
        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (email, password, status, empid, name, area, manager, record) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $email, $repEmail, $status, $employeeID, $FullName, $area, $manager, $record_locator);
            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            }
        }
```

Added an echo to double check we're grabbing the values. Success! We are!

echo    'Check to ensure we are grabbing the values';

```
echo    '<td>'. $user_rl    .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $status .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $area   .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $region .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $fullname   .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $manager    .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $position   .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $mobilenumber   .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $project_manager    .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $ipad_email .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $email  .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $team_leader    .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $regional   .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $title  .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $startdate  .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $empid  .'</td><br>';
```

DB SCHEME

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `memberss` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `empid` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `record` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `area` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `position` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mobilenumber` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `project_manager` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ipad_email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `regional` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `startdate` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Its either one of two things; either my DB Table isnt settup correctly or my main body script isnt functioning correctly.

I am getting NO ERRORS. Even when I attempt to catch errors on posting. Which leads me towards the table isnt setup correctly??

Thank you for any and all help.

P.S. for the witty ones; yes I have my DB connection file just didnt include it in the body of the code

Comment: Rather than `header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');` you should check for errors,  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php..or additionally and log the errors. You'll also want to exit after the `header`.

Comment: I did that, and no errors kicked out :(

Comment: Your scheme has `\`name\` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,` your insert doesn't have a `name` column. Your insert also has `manager` which doesn't exist in your scheme. I don't think you are using that error reporting correctly.

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Check your error logs as you're not spitting errors out to the screen. You'll find lot's of information there.

Comment: I understand where to locate the error logs, I have none... @JayBlanchard

Comment: You have no error logs?

Comment: That is correct... That is why I cannot figure this out, and its driving me nuts.

Comment: Then there is something *seriously* wrong with your web server. You need to get that fixed so that you can properly troubleshoot any issues you may be having.

Comment: Do you see an error  with my code? Or ?? I have error logs on anything else that I do, but THIS script...

Comment: I don't see the exact error but I do know that your query is failing. Since you're not including error checking in your script *and* you don't, as you say, have any error logs it would be hard for us to pinpoint the exact error you're having.

Comment: @JayBlanchard can you steer me in the right direction to grab the error from my if statement on errors? Maybe Im doing it wrong? Edit; but why would my bottom script work, but my top one wont? Read my OP I have a working version of the script and a non working version.

Comment: I read the whole thing. You need to [start here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have figured out what I did wrong.**

I wasnt passing enough

`VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

I was also not binding enough strings.

`$insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssss'` to match my

`if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (values)"))`

Comment: You need to figure out what is wrong with your server/PHP. There is an error message that is thrown for that error.

Comment: Yes, I understand you got it working however you should have been getting errors. I suspect there is something wrong with your error reporting.

Comment: For educational purposes (I am fairly new with PHP) how would I structure my error reporting to report what I was doing wrong? @chris85

Comment: So with prepare you get `mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.`. So with an error you won't enter`if ($insert_stmt)
    {` so you should put an else and output the error there using http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php or that is my interpretation from the manual, I don't use `mysqli` though so I can't say from experience.